# What's special about a "space" character in an "expr match" regexp?

Tags: regex

In a bash shell, I set line like so:

```
line="total active bytes:         256"
```

Now, I just want to get the digits from that line so I do:

```
echo $(expr match "$line" '.*\([[:digit:]]*\)' )
```

and I don't get anything.  But, if I add a space character before the first backslash in the regexp, then it works:

```
echo $(expr match "$line" '.* \([[:digit:]]*\)' )
```

Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The space isn't special at all. What's happening is that in the first case, the `.*` matches the entire string (i.e., it matches "greedily"), including the numbers, and since you've quantified the digits with `*` (as opposed to `\+`), that part of the regex is allowed to match 0 characters.

By putting a space before the digit match, the first part can only match up to but not including the last space in the string, leaving the digits to be matched by `\([[:digit:]]*\)`.

Comment: Is there any way to extract the complete number without having to specify the space before it, ie., any way to make the `.*` non-greedy, or make the `\+` greedy?

Comment: @awardak You could try `'[^[:digit:]]*\([[:digit:]]*\)'`